# Used VWP only for transit, now want to enter US for 90 days

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, french-citizens

I'm a French citizen with an approved ESTA.
I was flying from Thailand to Mexico with a 7hr transit in LA (had to go through border control and get a stamp). Indeed left US after a few hours.

I stay in Mexico for 3 weeks and really want to re-enter US (this time for traveling).
I'm not planning to work and have enough money (took a 1yr break from school for this trip, that's why I want to use my VWP for the max 90 days).
As I understand, currently I'll have 90 days *minus* my stay in Mexico for my re-entering.

My questions:
Is there something I can do/say/show so the border officer will grant me a new stamp for 90 days?
If so, better go by land or by air?
If not, is using the automated kiosks can help with something (maybe they give 90 days without messing with the Mexico/Canada issue)?

Comment: You can spend a couple of days in a country farther south, such as Panama or Costa Rica...

Comment: You could also apply for a B-2 visa, which generally allows you to stay for six months.

Comment: @MichaelHampton wouldn't Guatemala or Belize be enough ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Yes, but you would have to want to go there!

Comment: Cuba would be another option.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys!    Can I apply for a B-2 visa from inside the states?    It might be cheaper then the flights to another country....

Comment: Since you are travelling for a year and already on the American continent, do you plan on spending any time in South America? If yes, doing that (not merely a run to some small country to circumvent the VWP limitations but a few months of travel) before returning to the US should do the trick. Some of these countries are quite cheap, too.

Comment: Or, change your itinerary to bypass the US. There _are_ flights available to Mexico from the Far East which do not enter the US, though they may be more expensive. (for instance AM099 PVG-TIJ)

Comment: @MichaelHampton The language makes it sound like they're already in Mexico, so that doesn't seem like an option for them but might be good advice for other people considering the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Salut alon !

Unfortunately, you cannot apply for a B2 visitor visa while in the US. You would have to go to a US consulate in Mexico (or some other country) and apply as a "Third Country National."

If you were to go to a consulate in Mexico, there is an application process here

> http://mexico.usembassy.gov/visas/non-immigrant-visas/how-to-apply.html

Bonne chance, et courage !